# URLForResource alway returns nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I created a project without checking "use CoreData". The Project name is "glossary"

Now I changed my mind and so for I added an data model usinng Add->New File->Resource->Data Model->gave it the name Glossary->didn`t select any class->Finish.

The next step was to design my Data Model.
Then I added the needed Code to my AppDelegate.
For all Steps i was following this Tutorial:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH1-SW1

My problem now is located in this line:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"glossary" withExtension:@"momd"]
```

modelURL is always nill
Creating an extra NSBundle Ref and calling mainBundle shows me that this is working, however i don`t know if it is really the right path.

Doing the same Steps on an project with selected "use CoreData" while creating works great.

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 11):

It has to do with [model versioning](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html). You want to add a versioned model (item in Xcode project tree will have `.xcdatamodeld` extension) and then your code will run smoothly.

In Xcode 4 when you add a new Core Data file it is versioned by default. Even if you added Core Data support after project creation.

If you don't plan to have model versions, just use `.mom` in your code.

Comment: YES! Thank you! I was stuck with that one for 3 hours today. I didn't want to create a new model for the iOS version of an app I'd already made for OS X, so I checked off "Use Core Data" on my new iOS app, then tossed out the xcdatamodeld file and replaced it with the xcdatamodel from my old OS X app. It'd be nice if Apple chose less crappy extensions to make the difference more noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100 % sure, but URLForResource does work for files only and `momd` is directory.

URLForResource documentation: The method first looks for a matching resource **file** in the nonlocalized resource directory of the specified bundle. (In Mac OS X, this directory is typically called Resources but in iOS, it is the main bundle directory.) If a matching resource **file** is not found, it then looks in the top level of any available language-specific “.lproj” directories. (The search order for the language-specific directories corresponds to the user’s preferences.) It does not recurse through other subdirectories at any of these locations. For more details see Bundles and Localization.

Comment: Yes is red this already but as I found exactly this line in the tutorial and as I wrote creating the project with checked "Use Core Data for storage" it works fine. So momd should not be a directory. I tried to search in the Finder for momd but the finder hasen`t found anything (no directory or file). Well for me thats very strange :)

Comment: Ouch, my mistake, I just replaced momd with .xcdatamodel[d] in my mind, sorry for confusion.